# How to intepret <defunct> c++ process ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, defunct

I'm running some C++ code (8 independent processes running on Ubuntu with 8 cores).

I'm launching the C processes using python:

```
def runC():
    numThreads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    threads = []
    for i in range(numThreads):
        args = ("./cprogram", arg1,arg2,arg3)
        popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        threads.append(popen)

    for t in threads:
       t.wait()
       output = t.stdout.read()
       err = t.stderr.read()
       if len(output) > 0:
          print "output: " + output
       if len(err) > 0:
          print "err: " + err
```

I keep getting "defunct" processes.  What does that mean?  Why did this happen to me?

Comment: This is far too vague to even know what you're talking about, let alone answer any questions.  Can you please give a more detailed description.

Comment: thanks @PaulEvans ;)  I've elaborated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's the t.wait() that is causing the zombie process. Depending on the order that the jobs finish, there will be some in a zombie state until the t.wait() gets around to them. It's not really a problem, which is what I wanted to be sure of.